# AngularJS: Add Elements to <li> dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am unable to populate list on clicking Add button. Problem is when I change the text field again, My List data gets changed (binding), how to avoid that?

**HTML**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="projectManager">Project Manager(s)</label>
    <div class="row controls" >
        <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Manager name" ng-model="pm.name">
        <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Manager type" ng-model="pm.type">
        <button type="button" ng-click="addManagersForm()">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row controls" >
        <ul><li ng-repeat="tPm in pms">{{tPm.name}}</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('myContrl',["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.pms = [];

    $scope.addManagersForm = function() {
        console.log($scope.pm);
        $scope.pms.push($scope.pm);
    };

}]);
```

Comment: You have mis-matched quotes in your example. Is that just a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you are pushing the `$scope.pm` object into the array, and that object is binded in the form.

Just create a new object and you will be fine:

```
$scope.addManagersForm = function() {
    var pm = $scope.pm;
    $scope.pm = {}; // Do this to clean up the form fields
    $scope.pms.push(pm);
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Creating new var make sense.
I have now replaced the code with single line 
[Thanks @David Riccitelli for angular.copy() suggestion]
$scope.pms.push(angular.copy($scope.pm));
And Voila!

Answer (score 1):

It's because instances are passed by reference. You can use [angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) to create a deep copy of it.

See this example Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/d8HwXzTBK61sMuwLollW

The updated code:

**HTML page**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myContrl">
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="projectManager">Project Manager(s)</label>
    <div class="row controls" >
        <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Manager name" ng-model="pm.name">
        <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Manager type" ng-model="pm.type">
        <button type="button" ng-click="addManagersForm(pm)">&nbsp;&nbsp;Add&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row controls" >
        <ul><li ng-repeat="tPm in pms">{{tPm.name}}</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('myContrl',["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.pms = [];

    $scope.addManagersForm = function(pm) {
        console.log(pm);
        $scope.pms.push(angular.copy(pm));
    };

}]);
```